# Open data with GIS locations of bombing or artillery attacks in Ukraine

Tags: data-request, geospatial, ukraine

I was wondering if anyone know of a dataset that is tracking the GIS locations of the bombing and artillery attacks in Ukraine? I was particularly interested in Kiev or Kharkiv regions, but I will take whatever I can get. If anyone know of data like this, please respond with the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This website](https://maphub.net/Cen4infoRes/russian-ukraine-monitor) looks like it has the data you are looking for. You could reach out to the owners of the site to see if they would send you the raw data. Another potential hit is [ACLED](https://acleddata.com/#/dashboard) which has geo-located conflict instances.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks so much for these links. I think the ACLED site also has a special Ukraine section, https://acleddata.com/ukraine-crisis/#dash . Thanks again.